# Does the Savoy theatre London allow shopping bags in the theatre?

Tags: london

I'm going to watch a show at the Savoy Theatre in London and planned to do some shopping beforehand. Will I be allowed to take this in with me? The website states that the cloakroom will not accept rucksacks, or suitcases??

Comment: If you've just got a few bags, even if the cloakroom doesn't accept them you can probably just take them in and put them down by your feet/under your seat; if you've got an absolute tonne of shopping you might struggle. But I don't know for certain hence the comment rather than answer.

Comment: Don't know about the Savoy Theatre specifically, but in most London theatres there is very very limited space, so having shoppings bags at your feet or under your seat is probably not an option.

Comment: @jcaron I've not been to the Savoy specifically but in London theatres there's still usually a bit of space between your bottom and the floor, especially if (like most) it has tip-up seats. There can sometimes be some behind the seat in front of you as well in the case of tiered seating.

Answer (score 5):

When I saw a show at the Savoy Theatre earlier this year I brought an empty shopping bag with me (when I exited it contained the programme for the show). I've done that in several theatres, and also entered with a shopping bag containing the programme from a show I saw earlier that day, or the ticket for the show I was going to see later that day. I know I've had other small things in a shopping bag entering theatres in London, I also know that I've been at the Savoy theatre before, but I don't remember if I had anything in my bag back then.

As at most theatres, the guards at the doors wanted to look into my (and everyone else's) bag.

As you can't leave your bag in the cloakroom, you will have to bring it into the auditorium with you (or leave it, where it will probably be removed), so don't bring a ton of shopping. I just put my bag on the floor beneath my seat and like that everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely to be allowed to take into the auditorium a shopping bag that's small enough to fit under your seat (they'll probably want to search it first for security purposes). There may not be very much space under your seat, some London theatres are quite cramped.

If you need to store something bigger (e.g. rucksack or suitcase) then I suggest one of the following:

- Left Luggage at Charing Cross station (a few minutes walk from the theatre). Book here: https://www.left-baggage.co.uk/en
- "Stasher" luggage storage service in the shop Gift London, which is on The Strand and looks to be very near the theatre. Book here: https://stasher.com/luggage-storage/london/stashpoints/the-strand-gift-london-856252379185 There's also a similar service named BagBnB which has a location nearby (it doesn't give the exact location until you pay - it may actually be the exact same shop as for Stasher): https://bagbnb.com/luggage-storage/london/trafalgar-square/luggage-storage-charing-cross-station

The "left luggage" services at the station are well-known and reliable. I don't know anyone who's used the Stasher/BagBnB services, but I'd expect them to be ok.

Hope that helps. BTW traffic in Savoy Court drives on the right-hand side of the road, don't get run over. :)

Comment: Victoria Coach Station is also a nice place to store bags, think it's about £5.50 for up to 24 hours storage. Though it's about 20-30 mins away from Savoy Theatre.